# Concatenate sting from different tables in sql server 2017 below versions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `User_details` and `Level_details`.

`User_details` table:

```
ID     Name
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       D
5       E
```

`Level_details` table:

```
trns_id    Lvl   usr_id
66          1      1
66          1      5
77          1      2
77          2      3
66          2      4
66          2      3
```

I am expecting the result like:

```
trns_id   Lvl    name
66         1     A, E
66         2     D, C
77         1     B
77         2     C
```

Please suggest the query that should work in lower version of SQL server(below SQl 17).

Comment: Which SQL Server version?

Comment: @jarlh one earlier than 2017...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Comment: @DaleK , I am trying the below query:                                                                                          SELECT l.trns_id,l.lvl,  
STUFF  
(  
    (  
      SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ CAST(u.name AS VARCHAR(MAX))  
      FROM User_Details u, Level_Details l   
      WHERE u.id=l.usr_id   
      FOR XMl PATH('')  
    ),1,2,''  
)  as Name
FROM Level_Details l 
GROUP BY l.trns_id, l.lvl
ORDER BY l.trns_id, l.lvl

Answer (score 0):

You can use STRING_AGG to get concatenated results.

```sql
SELECT l.trans_id, l.lvl, STRING_AGG(u.Name, ',') AS name
FROM Level_Details as l
INNER JOIN User_Details as u
ON u.ID = l.usr_id
group by l.trans_id, l.lvl
```